# Accessing a users google drive

Tags: python, django, google-api, django-allauth, google-api-python-client

I have a django site that uses [Django allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for users to log in using their google account and grant permission to their google drive. Once logged in, `django-allauth` saves a token for that user. This part all works correctly.

How do I now access the user's google drive (who has granted permission), to list the available files? Presumably this needs to use the token that was saved thanks to `django-allauth`.

I have installed the [python google api client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation) but am struggling to figure out how to use the user's token to list the content of their google drive.

There is a flask example [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app?authuser=1#example) which im trying to modify for use in a django project utilizing `django-allauth`. The sign in flow works correctly, but `django-allauth` does not ensure that google drive access is requested. I've tried updating my settings as per [this](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#django-configuration):

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "google": {
        "SCOPE": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
        ],
        "AUTH_PARAMS": {"access_type": "offline"},
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There haven't been any answers posted so im just posting what I ended doing. It doesn't look like `django-allauth` can be used both for regular google authentication and api auth.

So for the time being a user first has to sign in to the site using their google account which is handled by `django-allauth`. Then once they're logged in they can select to grant access to their google drive which then kicks off a new auth flow for that (using the [Google python api client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation))

Comment: Hey @darkpool, do you happen to have any guidance from what you came up with? I feel like google's documentation on both the authentication and basic functionality (sharing, granting permission, etc) with apiv3 is pretty sparce on this...

Answer (score 2):

For anyone reading this now, the current release of allauth does support API auth.

You need to provide the complete URL (e.g. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) instead of just the scope name (e.g. email) in the SCOPE list for scopes that aren't in the default list within allauth.

Comment: Do you have an example of a call to the API using this? That would be incredibly helpful - thanks in advance!

Comment: Agreed. If you have an example, that would be very helpful!